# Python nested for loop in RGB average

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I've got a rather slow point in some code I'm looking to optimize. In a masked image, I'm calculating the average of R, G, and B channels. I'd like to get rid of the nested for loops, and not really sure how to accomplish that. Any thoughts?

```
maskimage = cv2.imread(filename)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(maskimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
boundaries = [([25, 146, 190], [62, 174, 250])]
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
        # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
        lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
        upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")
        # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
        # the mask
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(bgimage, bgimage, mask = mask)
        meanblue = 0
        meangreen = 0
        meanred = 0
        count = 0
        H, W, b = masked_img.shape
        for i in range(0,H,1):
           for j in range(0,W,1):
            if masked_img[i,j,0] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,1] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,2] > 1:
                meanblue = meanblue + masked_img[i,j,0]
                meangreen = meangreen + masked_img[i,j,1]
                meanred = meanred + masked_img[i,j,2]
                count = count+1
        if count !=0:
            omeanb = meanblue/count
            omeang = meangreen/count
            omeanr = meanred/count
        if count ==0:
            omeanb = 255
            omeang = 255
            omeanr = 255
```

Comment: have a look to itertools.product: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Try `np.average(masked_img, axis=-1)`, plus modifications to suit your other needs.

Comment: np.average seems promising, though I'm a bit confused. printing that out gives: [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the innermost two nested loops with a vectorized approach.

Thus, one could replace this -

```
H, W, b = masked_img.shape
for i in range(0,H,1):
   for j in range(0,W,1):
    if masked_img[i,j,0] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,1] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,2] > 1:
        meanblue = meanblue + masked_img[i,j,0]
        meangreen = meangreen + masked_img[i,j,1]
        meanred = meanred + masked_img[i,j,2]
        count = count+1
```

with this -

```
mask = (masked_img > 1).any(2)
count = mask.sum()
mean_bgr = (masked_img*(mask[...,None])).sum(axis=(0,1))
```

One could go a bit *adventurous* and use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) at the last step and that might give a further boost to performance, like so -

```
mean_bgr = np.einsum('ijk,ij->k',masked_img.astype(int),mask)
```

**Runtime test**

Function definitions -

```
def original_app(masked_img):
    meanblue = 0
    meangreen = 0
    meanred = 0
    count = 0
    H, W, b = masked_img.shape
    for i in range(0,H,1):
       for j in range(0,W,1):
        if masked_img[i,j,0] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,1] > 1 or masked_img[i,j,2] > 1:
            meanblue = meanblue + masked_img[i,j,0]
            meangreen = meangreen + masked_img[i,j,1]
            meanred = meanred + masked_img[i,j,2]
            count = count+1
    return [meanblue, meangreen, meanred], count

def vectorized_app1(masked_img):
    mask = (masked_img > 1).any(2)
    count = mask.sum()
    mean_bgr = (masked_img*(mask[...,None])).sum(axis=(0,1))
    return mean_bgr, count

def vectorized_app2(masked_img):
    mask = (masked_img > 1).any(2)
    count = mask.sum()
    mean_bgr = np.einsum('ijk,ij->k',masked_img.astype(int),mask)
    return mean_bgr, count
```

Timings -

```
In [235]: # Random image input array
     ...: masked_img = np.random.randint(0,255,(512,512,3)).astype('uint8')

In [236]: original_app(masked_img)
Out[236]: ([33273503, 33274596, 33323215], 262144)

In [237]: vectorized_app1(masked_img)
Out[237]: (array([33273503, 33274596, 33323215], dtype=uint32), 262144)

In [238]: vectorized_app2(masked_img)
Out[238]: (array([ 33273503,  33274596,  33323215]), 262144)

In [239]: %timeit original_app(masked_img)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.08 s per loop

In [240]: %timeit vectorized_app1(masked_img)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop

In [241]: %timeit vectorized_app2(masked_img)
10 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop
```

That's a **`100+x`** speedup there!

Comment: mean_bgr = (masked_img*(mask[...,None])).sum(axis=(0.1)) seems to have an error, as I'm getting values above 255. however, the np.einsum seems to do the trick, much faster than before. Can you explain what is going on with ijk, ij->k ?

Comment: @MarkBrown Yes, you need to scale down by `255`. As stated in the post, we are only removing the nested loops. So, everything else has to be done, which includes the next two IF conditional statements. Hope that makes sense. Also, the `einsum` is a bit complicated thing to explain. I would advise following the official docs on it.

Comment: @MarkBrown Please check out the edits. Sorry I meant scaling down by `count` still remains after which the values would be within `[0,255]`.

Comment: Soooo much faster. I had been waiting hours previously, and am down to minutes.

Comment: @MarkBrown That's lovely!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having nested for loops, you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [(i,j) for i, j in product((1,2,3), (4, 5, 6))]
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: This'll still have to go through all those (i, j) pairs and do the math in python. It's not much of an improvement, since instead of nested for loops doing N (i, j) pairs you have a single for loop doing N (i, j) pairs.

Comment: Yea, I'm looking for performance improvement by taking out the loops, and itertools doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Indeed, it's just a bit more elegant but if Numpy has a specific way of making your life easier and code more readable, use it, as advised by lija.